# usercontrol with button content binding

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol that I want to reuse but I can't seem to find a way how to change the button's content. I jave already tried everything I have searched in here. If somebody can tell me what is missing , I would really appreciate it as I have been trying to figure this out all day. here is my code:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SamplePopupWPF.UserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Uid="btnLeft" Name="btnBindCmd" Height="23" Click="AddCommand" Content="{Binding ContentText, Mode=TwoWay}", DataContext="UserControl1"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code for user control:

```
 public string ContentText
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(ContentTextProperty);  }
        set { SetValue(ContentTextProperty, value); }
    }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentText",     typeof (String),  typeof (UserControl1),new IPropertyMetadata(String.Empty,textChangedCallback));

    static void textChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        UserControl1 c = (UserControl1) d;
        c.ContentText = e.NewValue as String;
   }
```

here is the Somepage using the control:"

```
    <Grid >
            <user:UserControl1 x:Name="btnTEST" AddCommandClick="onBtnClick" ContentText="{Binding OtherCmd, ElementName=UserControl1}" />

    </Grid>
```

code for Somepage using the control:

```
public string OtherCmd
    {

        get { return _otherCmd; }
        set
        {
            _otherCmd = value;
            //if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                NotifyProperty("OtherCmd");

        }
    }

 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            OtherCmd = "helloTest";
    }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

At some point I have not used all codes I placed above but still not working. Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The button is bound to ContentText but has no DataContext, so it is inheriting it from its parent. You probably want to do this:

```
<UserControl
        x:Name="root"
        x:Class="SamplePopupWPF.UserControl1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Uid="btnLeft" Name="btnBindCmd" Height="23" Click="AddCommand" Content="{Binding ContentText, Mode=TwoWay}", DataContext="UserControl1"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note the root `Grid` has its `DataContext` set to the `UserControl` itself. Thus, the `Binding` in the `Button` will attempt to resolve a `ContentText` property on the `UserControl` instance.

Answer (score 1):

In your UserControl1.xaml.cs write `this.DataContext = this;` under the `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor.

This is because you can not assign a datacontext the way you are doing in your UserControl1.xaml. Kent shows the correct way.

Comment: I tried the suggestion above but It's not working :(. Also, please notice that in my sample, the one using the usercontrol is Somepage.xaml, and the button content text will be coming fro the Somepage.cs code. Please any other suggestion? thank u!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to inherit your somepage with INOTIFYPROPERTYCHANGED like this

```
public class Subject :INotifyPropertyChanged
{

}
```